# Looking for a simple page-based pop-over message box

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add (with as minimal change to a page as possible) the ability to display a pop-over (i.e. not an actual OS dialog, but part of the page) message box on my homepage that I can call with javascript.

In the worst case I suppose I could resort to the `alert()` call, but I find these annoying and obtrusive and just want something unobtrusive that will only affect the page.

Something like those pop-over picture boxes you see, but for text, maybe with a headline or something and a close box or 'OK' button.

I tried searching for it, but all I can find are tutorials on using javascript `alert()`.

**Update:** I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093324/message-box-like-facebook), which has some good links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this before: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos